# Really strange behavior with Linux Shell Scripts

Tags: linux, shell, debian

i am really wondering why Linux (Debian Squeeze) is acting kind of crazy.
I've been trying to execute a simple test.sh script in my webapps directory:

```
/var/www/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/bin/
```

How to execute a script? Well, that would be done by entering:

**EDIT: ITS NOT ABOUT WRONG (FORGOTTEN) PERMISSIONS:**

```
chmod +x test.sh 

./test.sh
```

which now gives me the following:

```
-bash: ./test.sh: No permission
```

test.sh is looking like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello!"
```

What the hek? Copying/Moving test.sh to my home directory and execute it again, which gives me:

```
Hello!
```

which is actually the output from my test.sh file. So, it doesnt work in my webapp directory but it works in home?

**My researches:**

Trying to execute the script with sudo rights:

When executing the script with sudo the script simply does nothing. No messages at all.

Trying to execute it via

```
. test.sh
```

**It works! But why?**

Comment: . test.sh works because you are reading the script and sourcing it, not executing it. sh test.sh would work as well.

Comment: Im not sure i am understanding correctly. I mean it gives me "Hello!" so it actually executes the script, no?

Comment: When using . test.sh or sh test.sh, it merely reads the script, and the execution is done in the current shell in the case of the ., and done in separate shell in the case of sh - either way, the script itself is not executing, it is merely being read as a list of commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The volume the file is on is mounted `noexec`. You will need to remount it `exec`, but consider/research why it was mounted `noexec` in the first place.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. This was helpful. Is /www/ mounted noexec by default?

Comment: `/www` usually isn't mounted separately at all.